# Icon of ContextMenu doesn't show up

Tags: wpf, image, mvvm

with the answer to [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23563159/contextmenu-on-treeview-element-in-mvvm-style/23563835) I could solve my ContextMenu-Problem.
Now I wanted to show a little icon on the MenuItem. And it doesn't unfortunately.

Here's the code that doesn't work (I only set the image for the button! The Treeview should be similar):

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="ContextMenu.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid >
        <StackPanel>
            <!--To show that it works in principal:-->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}" />
            <Image Source="{Binding MyImage}" Width="25" Height="25"/>

            <Button Tag="{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Content="Click me">
                <Button.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.MyText,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContextMenu}}">
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.MyImage,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Button.ContextMenu>
            </Button>

            <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" >
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}">
                            <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.MyText, 
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>         
            </TreeView>

        </StackPanel>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindowVM.cs:**

```
public class MainWindowVM
{
    private ImageSource _myImage;
    public string MyText { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<TreeElement> MyList { get; set; }

    public ImageSource MyImage { get { return _myImage; } }

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        MyText = "This is my Text!";

        _myImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/ContextMenu;component/Resources/flash.png", UriKind.Relative));

        MyList = new ObservableCollection<TreeElement>();
        MyList.Add(new TreeElement("String 1"));
        MyList.Add(new TreeElement("String 2"));
    }
}

public class TreeElement
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TreeElement(string Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is likely causing your binding failure

```
RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContextMenu}
```

First off, any element automatically inherits the DataContext of it's visual parent, so your MenuItem will already get the proper DataContext to allow it to bind without the RelativeSource.

Secondly, and this is the harder part, anything that pops up in WPF (Context menus, tooltips, and a couple of expandable controls in the Xceed toolkit) aren't actually part of the visual tree and will not work properly with RelativeSource or ElementName bindings. Most things, however, seem to automatically populate their first child with the proper DataContext, and for this reason I often use a ContentControl to bind to at root level.

Hope this helps